# How do I deploy my chatbot model on google assistant?

Tags: dialogflow-es, pytorch, chatbot

I have developed my chatbot in PyTorch framework for college purposes. The model is working fine with log loss value of 0.5 and is able to answer questions appropriately. I have seen few productionization suggestions like fast.ai, flask and Django. But I want the model to be deployed on Google Assistant so that my end users can utilize the service of bot without any external installations. How do I have to integrate my PyTorch model to the Google Assistant on Dialogflow ?

Answer (score 0):

Google has published a series of Codelabs to help developers start building actions for the Google Assistant. Each module can be taken standalone or in a learning sequence with other modules.

In each module, the codelabs provide you with end-to-end instructions on how to build Actions from given software requirements and how to test your code. They also teach the necessary concepts and best practices for implementing Actions that give users high-quality conversational experiences.

You can start [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/index.html#0).